# Zend Framework, trying to link to a registration page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a wordpress page with a theme that utilizes zend framework. I really like the modal login and forgot password window however I would like the "Create an account" button to link to my registration url e.g. mysite.com/register/ instead of opening the #registration_panel as shown on the second screenshot. Is this possible without breaking the login/forgot password forms? I want the registration to take place on a separate page, not in a modal, however I still want the login process to go through the modal to make it faster for my users to login.

[image: login modal image]

[image: registration modal image]

This is the code:

```
      <div class="login_register_stuff">
        <!-- Login/Register Modal forms - hidden by default to be opened through modal -->
        <div id="login_panel" class="loginbox-popup mfp-hide">
            <div class="inner-container login-panel">
                <h3 class="m_title"><?php _e( "SIGN IN YOUR ACCOUNT TO HAVE ACCESS TO DIFFERENT FEATURES", 'zn_framework' ); ?></h3>
                <form id="login_form" name="login_form" method="post" class="zn_form_login"
                      action="<?php echo site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ?>">

                    <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form kl-fw-form">
                        <input type="text" id="kl-username" name="log" class="form-control inputbox"
                               placeholder="<?php _e( "eg: james_smith", 'zn_framework' ); ?>"/>
                        <label><?php _e( "USERNAME", 'zn_framework' ); ?></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form kl-fw-form">
                        <input type="password" id="kl-password" name="pwd" class="form-control inputbox"
                               placeholder="<?php _e( "type password", 'zn_framework' ); ?>"/>
                        <label><?php _e( "PASSWORD", 'zn_framework' ); ?></label>
                    </div>

                    <?php do_action( 'login_form' ); ?>

                    <label class="zn_remember" for="kl-rememberme">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="kl-rememberme" value="forever"/>
                        <?php _e( " Remember Me", 'zn_framework' ); ?>
                    </label>

                    <input type="submit" id="login" name="submit_button" class="btn zn_sub_button btn-fullcolor btn-md"
                           value="<?php _e( "LOG IN", 'zn_framework' ); ?>"/>

                    <input type="hidden" value="login" class="" name="zn_form_action"/>
                    <input type="hidden" value="zn_do_login" class="" name="action"/>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $current_url; ?>" class="zn_login_redirect" name="submit"/>

                    <div class="links">
                        <?php if ( (bool) get_option( 'users_can_register' ) ) { ?>
                        <a href="#register_panel" class="create_account kl-login-box"><?php _e( "CREATE AN ACCOUNT", 'zn_framework' ); ?></a> <span class="sep"></span>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <a href="#forgot_panel" class="kl-login-box"><?php _e( "FORGOT YOUR PASSWORD?", 'zn_framework' ); ?></a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- end login panel -->

        <?php if ( (bool) get_option( 'users_can_register' ) ) { ?>

            <div id="register_panel" class="loginbox-popup register-popup mfp-hide">
                <div class="inner-container register-panel">
                    <h3 class="m_title"><?php _e( "CREATE ACCOUNT", 'zn_framework' ); ?></h3>

                    <form id="register_form" name="login_form" method="post" class="zn_form_login"
                          action="<?php echo site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post' ) ?>">
                        <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form kl-fw-form">
                            <input type="text" id="reg-username" name="user_login" class="form-control inputbox"
                                   placeholder="<?php _e( "type desired username", 'zn_framework' ); ?>"/>
                            <label><?php _e( "USERNAME", 'zn_framework' ); ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form kl-fw-form">
                            <input type="text" id="reg-email" name="user_email" class="form-control inputbox"
                                   placeholder="<?php _e( "your-email@website.com", 'zn_framework' ); ?>"/>
                            <label><?php _e( "EMAIL", 'zn_framework' ); ?></label>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form kl-fw-form">
                            <input type="password" id="reg-pass" name="user_password" class="form-control inputbox"
                                   placeholder="<?php _e( "*****", 'zn_framework' ); ?>"/>
                            <label><?php _e( "PASSWORD", 'zn_framework' ); ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form kl-fw-form">
                            <input type="password" id="reg-pass2" name="user_password2" class="form-control inputbox"
                                   placeholder="<?php _e( "*****", 'zn_framework' ); ?>"/>
                            <label><?php _e( "CONFIRM PASSWORD", 'zn_framework' ); ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group kl-fw-form">
                            <input type="submit" id="signup" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-fullcolor btn-md"
                                   value="<?php _e( "CREATE MY ACCOUNT", 'zn_framework' ); ?>"/>
                        </div>

                        <input type="hidden" value="register" name="zn_form_action"/>
                        <input type="hidden" value="zn_do_login" name="action"/>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $current_url; ?>"
                               class="zn_login_redirect" name="submit"/>

                        <div class="links">
                            <a href="#login_panel" class="kl-login-box"><?php _e( "ALREADY HAVE AN ACCOUNT?", 'zn_framework' ); ?></a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end register panel -->
        <?php } ?>

        <div id="forgot_panel" class="loginbox-popup forgot-popup mfp-hide">
            <div class="inner-container forgot-panel">
                <h3 class="m_title"><?php _e( "FORGOT YOUR DETAILS?", 'zn_framework' ); ?></h3>
                <form id="forgot_form" name="login_form" method="post" class="zn_form_lost_pass"
                      action="<?php echo site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'login_post' ) ?>">
                    <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form kl-fw-form">
                        <input type="text" id="forgot-email" name="user_login" class="form-control inputbox"
                               placeholder="<?php _e( "...", 'zn_framework' ); ?>"/>
                        <label><?php _e( "USERNAME OR EMAIL", 'zn_framework' ); ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group kl-fw-form">
                        <input type="submit" id="recover" name="submit" class="btn btn-block zn_sub_button btn-fullcolor btn-md"
                               value="<?php _e( "SEND MY DETAILS!", 'zn_framework' ); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="links">
                        <a href="#login_panel" class="kl-login-box"><?php _e( "AAH, WAIT, I REMEMBER NOW!", 'zn_framework' ); ?></a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end register panel -->
    </div><!-- end login register stuff -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change line:
`<a href="#register_panel" class="create_account kl-login-box"><?php _e( "CREATE AN ACCOUNT", 'zn_framework' ); ?></a>`
with your registration href **mysite.com/register/** and remove popup class **kl-login-box**:
`<a href="/register/" class="create_account"><?php _e( "CREATE AN ACCOUNT", 'zn_framework' ); ?></a>`